# Use @Relate and unique

Tags: dart, aqueduct

How can I use Relate and unique using aqueduct ORM?

In my code I want that the userapp be unique?
If I try to put `@Column(unique: true)` I receive a error like this:

> *** Relationship 'userapp' on '_Professional' cannot both have 'Column' and 'Relate' metadata. To add flags for indexing or
>   nullability to a relationship, see the constructor for 'Relate'.

My code below:

```
class Professional extends ManagedObject<_Professional> implements _Professional {}

class _Professional {

  @primaryKey
  int id;
  @Relate(#professionals)
  Userapp userapp;
  @Column(defaultValue: 'true')
  bool active;  

  ManagedSet<ProfessionalSpecialty> professionalSpecialties;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the foreign key column underlying `userapp` is unique or not is determined by the inverse relationship property. In this case, the inverse is `Userapp.professionals`.

If `Userapp.professionals` is of type `Professional`, then a unique constraint is added to `userapp`; this is a 'has-one' relationship.

If `Userapp.professionals` is of type `ManagedSet<Professional>`, no unique constraint is applied; this is a 'has-many' relationship.

I'd guess that because you are using the plural form (`professionals`) that you are declaring a `ManagedSet<Professional>`. Change the declaration in the `_Userapp` table definition and make sure your inverse matches in `_Professional`:

```
class _Userapp {
  ...
  Professional professional;
}
class _Professional {
  ...
  @Relate(#professional)
  Userapp userapp;

}
```